# Connecting a single-colour LED strip to a RGBW controller

Tags: led, light, led-strip, rgb

I have a RGBW strip that is connected to a RGBW controller; Is it possible to connect a single-colour strip (rated at the same voltage) to the same controller? If so, how?

Thank you for your answers.

PS: I don't have access to the power supply of the controller.

Comment: Please provide diagrams and part numbers when posting

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A RGBW controller is essentially just four individual channels. You can connect a single color strip to the controller as long as it's done the right way (single color negative to the R G B or W, single color positive to the 12V) and the strip is within the single color current limit of the controller. Additionally, you may see a better color from G B or W, as R is often driven at a different frequency to make up for its brightness.